# User generated content and security

Tags: security, user-access

I'm gonna create a new site. I want to make the site as user generate able content site.

Basically this is my site's function. Users signup in my wordpress site, Submit content from wp-admin panel, some points will be given if the post approved by admin, later those points will be converted into some cash money.

So i need some advise. I heard wordpress has low security. If i let the users to create content from wp-admin, will they hack my site? is it good or bad to let them use wp-admin area? Is it possible to make those user content submission form from frontend? 
I'm not interested in plugin like TDO Mini Forms. Because i need points system.
Some tips needed. Thanks in advance

PS: **Can i use buddypress to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop listening to people who says PHP and WordPress is not secure. Its how you do it. You can do it in WordPress, without using BuddyPress. In fact you don't even need it for anything.

All you need to make default users contributors, and a small plugin which takes care of their points when their posts are approved.